# How to Deal with Lat/Lon Arrays with Multiple Dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, spatial-interpolation, pygrib

I'm working with Pygrib trying to get surface temperatures for particular lat/lon coordinates using the NBM grib data (available [here](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/nbm_home) if it helps).

I've been stuck trying to get an index value to use with representative data for a particular latitude and longitude. I was able to derive an index, but the problem is the latitude and longitude appear to have 2 coordinates each. I'll use Miami, FL (25.7617° N, 80.1918° W) as an example to illustrate this. Formatted to be minimum reproducible IF a grib file is provided.

```
def get_grib_data(self, gribfile, shortName):
    grbs = pygrib.open(gribfile)
    # Temp needs level specified
    if shortName == '2t':
        grib_param = grbs.select(shortName=shortName, level=2)
    # Convention- use short name for less than 5 chars
    # Else, use name
    elif len(shortName) < 5:
        grib_param = grbs.select(shortName=shortName)
    else:
        grib_param = grbs.select(name=shortName)
        data_values = grib_param[0].values
    # Need varying returns depending on parameter
    grbs.close()
    if shortName == '2t':
        return data_values, grib_param
    else:
        return data_values

# This function is used to find the closest lat/lon value to the entered one
def closest(self, coordinate, value): 
    ab_array = np.abs(coordinate - value)
    smallest_difference_index = np.amin(ab_array)
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(ab_array, axis=None), ab_array.shape)
    return ind

def get_local_value(data, j, in_lats, in_lons, lats, lons):
    lat_ind = closest(lats, in_lats[j])
    lon_ind = closest(lons, in_lons[j])

    print(lat_ind[0])
    print(lat_ind[1])
    print(lon_ind[0])
    print(lon_ind[1])
       
    if len(lat_ind) > 1 or len(lon_ind) > 1:
        lat_ind = lat_ind[0]
        lon_ind = lon_ind[0]
        dtype = data[lat_ind][lon_ind]
    else:
        dtype = data[lat_ind][lon_ind]

    return dtype 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tfile = # Path to grib file
    temps, param = grib_data.get_grib_data(tfile, '2t')
    lats, lons = param[0].latlons()
    j = 0
    in_lats = [25.7617, 0 , 0]
    in_lons = [-80.198, 0, 0]
    temp = grib_data.get_local_value(temps, j, in_lats, in_lons, lats, lons)
```

When I do the print listed, I get the following for indices:

```
lat_ind[0]: 182
lat_ind[1]: 1931
lon_ind[0]: 1226
lon_ind[1]: 1756
```

So if my lat/lon were 1 dimensional, I would just do temp = data[lat[0]][lon[0]], but in this case that would give non-representative data. How would I go about handling the fact that lat/lon are in 2 coordinates? I have verified that lats[lat_ind[0][lat_ind[1](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/nbm_home)] gives the input latitude and the same for longitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot evaluate "closeness" of latitudes independently of longitudes - you have to evaluate how close the pair of coordinates is to your input coordinates.

Lat/Lon are really just spherical coordinates.
Given two points (lat1,lon1) (lat2,lon2), closeness (in terms of great circles) is given by the angle between the spherical vectors between those two points (approximating the Earth as a sphere).

You can compute this by constructing cartesian vectors of the two points and taking the dot product, which is a * b * cos(theta) where theta is what you want.

```py
import numpy as np

def lat_lon_cartesian(lats,lons):

    lats = np.ravel(lats) #make both inputs 1-dimensional
    lons = np.ravel(lons)

    x = np.cos(np.radians(lons))*np.cos(np.radians(lats))
    y = np.sin(np.radians(lons))*np.cos(np.radians(lats))
    z = np.sin(np.radians(lats))
    return np.c_[x,y,z]

def closest(in_lats,in_lons,data_lats,data_lons):
    in_vecs = lat_lon_cartesian(in_lats,in_lons)
    data_vecs = lat_lon_cartesian(data_lats,data_lons)
    indices = []
    for in_vec in in_vecs: # if input lats/lons is small list then doing a for loop is ok
        # otherwise can be vectorized with some array gymnastics
        dot_product = np.sum(in_vec*data_vecs,axis=1)
        angles = np.arccos(dot_product) # all are unit vectors so a=b=1
        indices.append(np.argmin(angles))
    return indices

def get_local_value(data, in_lats, in_lons, data_lats, data_lons):
    raveled_data = np.ravel(data)
    raveled_lats = np.ravel(data_lats)
    raveled_lons = np.ravel(data_lons)
    inds = closest(in_lats,in_lons,raveled_lats,raveled_lons)
    dtypes = []
    closest_lat_lons = []
    
    for ind in inds:
                
        #if data is 2-d with same shape as the lat and lon meshgrids, then
        #it should be raveled as well and indexed by the same index
        dtype = raveled_data[ind]
        dtypes.append(dtype)

        closest_lat_lons.append((raveled_lats[ind],raveled_lons[ind]))
        #can return the closes matching lat lon data in the grib if you want
    return dtypes
```

Edit: Alternatively use interpolation.

```py
import numpyp as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

#assuming a grb object from pygrib
#see https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/api.html#example-usage


lats, lons = grb.latlons()
#source code for pygrib looks like it calls lons,lats = np.meshgrid(...)
#so the following should give the unique lat/lon sequences
lat_values = lats[:,0]
lon_values = lons[0,:]

grb_values = grb.values

#create interpolator
grb_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((lat_values,lon_values),grb_values)

#in_lats, in_lons = desired input points (1-d each)
interpolated_values = grb_interp(np.c_[in_lats,in_lons])

#the result should be the linear interpolation between the four closest lat/lon points in the data set around each of your input lat/lon points.
```

Dummy data interpolation example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lats = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> lons = np.array([4,5,6,7])
>>> lon_mesh,lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
>>> lon_mesh
array([[4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> lat_mesh
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> z = lon_mesh + lat_mesh #some example function of lat/lon (simple sum)
>>> z
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])
>>> from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
>>> lon_mesh[0,:] #should produce lons
array([4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> lat_mesh[:,0] #should produce lats
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> interpolator = RegularGridInterpolator((lats,lons),z)
>>> input_lats = np.array([1.5,2.5])
>>> input_lons = np.array([5.5,7])
>>> input_points = np.c_[input_lats,input_lons]
>>> input_points
array([[1.5, 5.5],
       [2.5, 7. ]])
>>> interpolator(input_points)
array([7. , 9.5])
>>> #7 = 1.5+5.5 : correct
... #9.5 = 2.5+7 : correct
...
>>>
```

Comment: This all makes sense and is really close! 1 issue: on the closest function, the dot product line gives this value error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1597,7035). 1597 is the dimension of the "data_lats" which makes sense, and 3 appears to just be the dimension for x, y, z for the in_lat/;on, but that isn't compatible as a dot product

Comment: @ZachRieck Hmm. I would expect the 2nd dimension of data_vecs to be 3 so that it would be something like broadcasting (3,) with (1597,3) which should return an array with shape (1597,3). The sum along axis 1 should add the three columns together to produce a (1597,) shape end result consisting of cosines of the angles. What are the shapes of the data_lats and data_lons arrays going into the lat_lon_cartesian function? Are they each 1-dimensional and the same size? If they are 2-dimensional but the same size, they might be meshgrid outputs, in which case we need to wrap them in np.ravel().

Comment: @ZachRieck I added the ravel lines in the lat_lon_cartesian function. If the grib lat and lon outputs have the same shape as one another, then ravel should reduce them both to be 1-dimensional, the same size, with both values for each combined lat/lon point being at the same index in both arrays.

Comment: @ZachRieck also added some ravels in the bottom of get_local_value() - I think that will make it work. For illustrative inputs [1,2,3] and [A,B,C,D], the meshgrids will be [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] and [[A,A,A],[B,B,B],[C,C,C],[D,D,D]]. It is a common way of doing a cartesian product of associating every point in the first list with every point in the second. "Raveling" basically collapses all these lists into flat lists but in the a way that preserves the index associations.

Comment: you really know your stuff thanks! I'll give this a shot. FYI, planning on upvoting and accepting as soon as I can verify the solution!

Comment: Going to list this here in case it is relevant later: in_lats and in_lons are the same length (1597) as are data_lats and data_lons (3744965)

Comment: so with these lines I get the right lat/lon pair: closest_lat, closest_lon = 
       data_lats[ind], data_lons[ind]
        print(closest_lat)
        print(closest_lon)
To get that, I did need to add this before the for loop:
data_lats = np.ravel(data_lats)
data_lons = np.ravel(data_lons)

The only issue is closest_lat and closest_lon aren't indices, so this line gives an error: dtype = data[closest_lat][closest_lon]

Comment: @ZachRieck Right - so I suspect the temps variable from the pygrib function, which gets named as data within the get_local_value function, is probably shaped the same way as the data_lats and data_lons variables. So what you can do is ravel that temps=data variable as well and use the same ind variable on it to get the dtype value that corresponds to the closest lat/lon point. I edited the answer above to do this with  dtype = np.ravel(data)[ind].

Comment: @ZachRieck Also you can use lat_ind,lon_ind = np.unravel_index(ind,data_lons.shape). To convert the single flattened "raveled" index into a pair of indices that correspond to the proper point in the original array shape.

Comment: @ZachRieck Tweaked it a bit so to call np.ravel() ahead of time and not every loop iteration in the "for ind in inds:" loop, which is unnecessary. Also - it occurred to me that you might actually want to interpolate between lat/lon points. If that is the case, then you should look into RegularGridInterpolator. You can give it the lats/lons/temps and it will produce a new interpolated function. You can simply plug in your input lats and lons and get the interpolated temp results. This would actually be much simpler. Let me know if that's what you want and I can post another answer showing how.

Comment: You sir deserve a gold star! This is great, thank you!

Comment: This is a great question and answer and I have nothing to add, except to suggest that both of you check out [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) if you aren't already aware. See especially the section on [working with multidimensional coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html). Xarray has a [grib reader](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#grib-format-via-cfgrib) built in. It doesn't solve this specific question, but makes plotting and a whole lot else way easier. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but wanted to put this here as a much simpler answer that should give you what you need by minimizing not only the x, but also the y distance:

```
coordinates = np.unravel_index((np.abs(lats - lat_to_find) + np.abs(lons - lon_to_find)).argmin(), lats.shape)
```

lats and lons should be your meshgrid of lats and lons, and then lat_to_find and lon_to_find are your lat/lon pair to find in your arrays. Then you have your indices which you can quickly index whatever variable(s) you need.